# Python - Renaming files inside .7z archives

Tags: python, 7zip

Do any of the existing Python APIs support renaming files inside .7z archives? I've been playing around with py7zlib, but so far I've not been able to figure out a way to rename files inside archives with it.

One other option I considered was just launching the 7z command line tool, but support for rename [wasn't added until 7-Zip 9.38 beta](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/feature-requests/1041/), which I don't have access to on this machine.

Edit: To clarify, I'd like to rename without just decompressing / recompressing.